# Basic stochastic inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Prove that
$$P(X \leq x\mid X >Y) \leq P(X \leq x).$$

I try to use the definition of conditional probability, but I can't get success.
$$P(X \leq x\mid X >Y) = \frac{P(X \leq x, X > Y)}{P(X >Y)} = \frac{P(Y < X \leq x)}{P(X >Y)}$$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $F(x) F(y) \leq  F(y)$. Hence, $F(x)-F(y) \leq F(x) [1-F(y)]$. In other words, $P\{y<X \leq x\} \leq P\{X \leq x\} P\{y<X\}$. If you integrate this with respect to the distribution of $Y$ (and use independence) you get $P\{Y<X \leq x\} \leq P\{X \leq x\} P\{Y<X\}$ which is the given inequality.

Comment: You can avoid the integration entirely by invoking instead that $F(x)F(Y) \le F(Y)$ a.s.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist The inequality is false without independence.  [ $X$ exp(1), Y=X^{2}, $0<x<1$ gives a counter-example]. How do you use independence in your proof?